# How do know what I got wrong when I ask a question

Tags: discussion, question-quality

My grammar is poor because of learning disabilities.
And my questions get auto flagged as poor a lot with no feedback on how to fix them. The [quality standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) are very unclear. What do I do? I do use spell check

Comment: maybe try using online tools to check grammar and spelling before you post.

Comment: i do use spell check

Comment: If so it must have indicated that gramer, pore, disableitys are all incorrect. Why didn't you fix the spelling of those words? And why didn't you capitalise the word I?

Comment: I will try using Grammarly

Comment: A spell checker is of no use if you don't react to what it suggests.

Comment: For your own sake and for the sake of your readers, ***please*** capitalise "i" and capitalise sentences. ***This doesn't require any skills***, only the willingness to change habits (in other words, learning disabilities is not an excuse you can use). You disadvantage yourself right from the beginning by not doing it. This alone could explain most of the downvotes. Making this change will also greatly enhance your chances in the job market.

Answer (score 9):

Honestly - Unless your spelling and grammar is so bad as to be unintellegible, folks don't generally penalise you just based on *that*.

Years ago, as a new contributor on Super User - folks used to tell me "You have good posts but man, your spelling and grammar is terrible"

So rather than focusing on what you can't do focus on what you can.

> A clear title.

I tend to recommend a KISS (Keep it Simple and Sensible) philisophy here

Broadly I use structures like  "I am trying to <do this> in <this> but I have <this>

Or can I use <something> to do <something> in <tool>.

A good title is simple and immediately lets the reader decide if your question is something they can tackle.

> A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
>
> Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.

I advocate a specific structure here

- Talk about your enviroment, things like OS, language, versions and such. Let the reader start with any information you will need
- What you are trying to do/need to know
- Your current situation - code snippet in question, what's not working, error messages relevant to the issue and so on, what you have tried so far, so folks don't retrace your steps, and it shoes you've made an effort.
- What you are trying to achieve

> Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability

This is *literally* the last point of many. I think the important part here is *effort* and to *show it*. I think no one's going to get mad at you for poor command of language with everything else being ok. If your post is otherwise good and useful, folks will help fix errors for you. I use spellcheck and it sometimes misses things - and people seem ok with fixing it

Comment: not the problem it's the auto flag